# With Objective-C SDK, Google Drive returns 503 Error when uploading a file with non-ASCII title

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

Since 27th June, when our app tries to upload a file to Google Drive, the server have started returning 503 error (below) when the title of the file is not written with ASCII ones.

```
"Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=503 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 503.)""
```

We looked into the problem and have found if the title is written in ascii, the error won't occur. We also tested filename like "日本語.txt" "中文简体繁体.txt" "한국어.txt" "русский язык.txt" and all of them ends with the error above. Of course, if we change the filename to an ascii text, the error vanishes.

I use google-api-objectivec-client library for Google Drive access and what I do is nothing strange - just setting the title property of a GTLDriveFile that is used on upload.

```
GTLDriveFile *file  = [GTLDriveFile object];
file.title          = title;
```

Our code had been working fine for months.

Is there any possible mistake on my uploading file to the server? If not, is there any workaround on the problem? Any help is welcome. Thanks.

P.S.
I also have tested the problem with "DriveSample" app included in the library. The same problem occurred by using "Upload" feature of the app.

---

30th June (added)

The filename problem seems lies only on "Client Library for iOS".
I tested "Client Library for Python" and found it works fine with non-ascii title.

In case "DriveSample" app I used for testing is not well maintained, I also downloaded another sample from Google called "DrEdit" for verify. Unfortunately, "DrEdit" also couldn't handle the non-ascii title on upload.

Then, I checked the URL each libraries accesses for upload.

```
Python: 
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=resumable&alt=json

Objective-C:
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/rpc?uploadType=resumable&prettyPrint=false
```

Python uses exactly the same URL as the Google Drive API Documentation.
However, Objective-C library uses different URL which is not documented.

Couldn't it be possible the URL Objective-C library accesses causes the non-ascii title conversion problem if the library has no problem? Maybe inter-server communication failure or something?

Still, any help is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems fixed on the server side on 3 July 21:30 PDT.
Thank you for the work, Google.